# How to get items from many to many relationships' one to many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, orm, relationship

I have 2 relationships:

1. Agents(many)-to-Properties(many) relationship (with a pivot table).
2. Properties(one)-to-Images(many) relationship (no pivot table).

So an Agent can have 10 Properties, and each Property will have 10 Images; therefore, Agent has 100 Images. (I do not want to create a relationship between the Agents and Images).

**Is there a query that will allow me get all of the Agent's Images?**

Something similar to `$agent->properties()->images()->get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hasManyThrough https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

In your Agent model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Images', 'App\Properties');
}
```

Then you can use

```
$agent->images()->get();
```

Comment: You can only use `hasManyThrough` when the intermediate relationship is a `hasOne` or `hasMany`. In this case, the intermediate relationship is a `belongsToMany`, so `hasManyThrough` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

So, how about two queries like:

```
<?php

$agent = new Agent();
$image = new Image();
$propertyIds = $agent->properties()->lists('id');
$images = $image->newQuery()->whereIn('property_id', $propertyIds)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`hasManyThrough('App\Image', 'App\Property')` works if you have a 1-Many (or 1-1) relationship to 1-Many relationship. But in my specific scenario I had a Many-Many relationship (with pivot) to 1-Many Relationship.

I ended up using this statement. Maybe this'll be useful to someone:

```
SELECT images.* FROM `agent_property` INNER JOIN images 
    ON agent_property.property_id = images.property_id 
WHERE agent_property.agent_id = '1'
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
return DB::table('agent_property')->join('images', 'agent_property.property_id', '=', 'images.property_id')->where('agent_property.agent_id', $this->id)->select('images.*');
```